What is the right way to play audio with ALSA LIB?
I am working on an embedded audio device, it is using kernel-5.10, and ALSA-LIB to play audio.
When I am trying to call snd_pcm_writei() to play audio, I got a little confused on what is the right way to set its input parameters and handle its return value.
Here is my code.
    /* Get periodsize from system */
        snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(hw_params, &periodsize, NULL);

        left = frames;
        sent = 0;
        while (left > 0) {
            sent = (left > periodsize) ? periodsize : left;
            rc = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buf, sent);
            if (rc < 0) {
                if (rc == -EAGAIN) {
                    usleep(1000);
                }
                rc = snd_pcm_recover(pcm_handle, rc, 0);
                if (rc < 0) {
                    snd_pcm_prepare(pcm_handle);
                }
            } else if (rc == 0) {
/* How to handle this case ?*/
            } else {
/* Samples less than were sent to audio-card */
                left -= rc;
                buf += rc * frame_size;
            }
        }

In my testing, the frames is 820, and periodsize is got from system, now it is 400. I am trying to sent data to audio-card upto the size of periodsize, is it correct?
Should I send data with frames of 820 directly to the audio card to play?
   snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buf, frames);

Updated with testing codes and testing results.
#ifdef TEST_APLAY
    frame_size = chan * 2;
    buf = databuf;
    left = data_frames;
    sent = 0;

    while (left > 0) {
        sent = (left > periodsize) ? periodsize : left;
        rc = snd_pcm_writei(hah->pcm_handle, buf, sent);
        if (rc == -EAGAIN || (rc >= 0 && (size_t)rc < sent)) {
            snd_pcm_wait(hah->pcm_handle, 10);
        } else if (rc == -EPIPE) {
            snd_pcm_recover(hah->pcm_handle, rc, 0); 
////            snd_pcm_prepare(hah->pcm_handle);
        } else if (rc < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (rc > 0) {
            left -= rc; 
            buf += rc * frame_size;
        }
    }   
#endif


And I got the following results (start and stop playing 10 times).
Playing/stoping quickly for times, pid: 3168
Got end of media, breaking
Got end of media, breaking
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Got end of media, breaking
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Got end of media, breaking
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
Got end of media, breaking

Above is tested in Ubuntu-20.04 X86_64 VM, with AC97 sound card.

Have to looked at aplay sources?

Good point, not read it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2180909/1216776

I read aplay source codes and the discussion in the link stark provided. I think I got 2 different answers. aplay seemed to feed sound card with date length of chunk_size, and send samples in a loop. But the SO link said I just need to write everything in one go. So which one should I follow?

@wangt13 It depends on requirements for your application. aplay is "semi-interactive", it can be interrupted by user. When you write entire buffer, the process calling snd_pcm_writei() is blocked until [almost] all buffer content is played.

Thanks for explaining the snd_pcm_writei(), my application is similar to aplay, there is a main thread getting input from user to stop its audio playing. In this case, which pattern should I use to send data to snd_pcm_writei(), packing data to period size and loops, or delivering the whole data in one go? I think the first one is better, which can make it be stopped quickly after each period, is my understanding correct?

@wangt13 Yes, it is correct. Actually when main thread exits, all threads are terminated and PCM handle descriptor is closed. On modern desktop systems, when asoundlib API is provided by pulseaudio, it terminates playback. However, I'm not sure what behavior will be on embedded system with native ALSA API. See also this answer and the article linked.
Another option is to use I/O event loop and call snd_pcm_writei() when poll descriptor becomes writable, but it is another story.

You can use whatever size you want. When the buffer is full, the write will wait or return -EAGAIN.

@CL, the application should play the audio without loss, and it should play audio with underrun as little as possible. So what is the right way to set parameters to snd_pcm_writei() and error handling when the data written is less than required??

Duplicate of How to properly handle xrun in ALSA programming when playing audio with snd_pcm_writei()? and Can we overcome underrun in alsa using snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size?

I read the similar discussions in SO, and want to know what does buffer mean in the discussion. Is it the buffer in user space to keep the audio data to be sent to write() function, or the buffer in the ALSA (I didn't set it)? My application is using 16384Bytes as data buffer, and ALSA periodsize is 400 (1 channel, sample rate 44100, bps is 16). The application loops to call writei() with periodsize of 400. It can hit underrun sometimes, I am not sure if I need (and how to) set up the latency in ALSA?
